# Is it possible to select HTML elements by their font color?

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery

I have a large HTML file containing event data, and I'd like to select elements based on font color. The elements don't contain unique ID's or classes, so this seems like my only option.

Can anyone recommend a solution in JavaScript, jQuery, or Python? Thank you!

Comment: Show us at least a small sample of your code so we know how to properly answer your question. Font colors can be set a number of different ways and each of them requires a completely different answer.

Comment: Sounds like the color is set in inline `style` attributes. If so, this would be relatively easy. As mentioned in previous comment a sample is needed as per [mcve]

Comment: @icecub Sure thing:
<span style="color:#FF2500">Glenwood Springs</span>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example if you store your html in some "html.txt" file

Then run this code on the file:

```
import re
f = open("html.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
dict1 = {}
for line in f:
    x = re.search(r"\"color:(.*)\"", line)
    if(x):
        if x.group(1) not in dict1:
            dict1[x.group(1)] = [line.strip()]
        else:
            dict1[x.group(1)].append(line.strip())
    else:
        continue
print(dict1)
```

**Contents of html.txt**

```
<span style="color:#FF2500">Glenwood Springs</span>
<span style="color:#FF2500">XYZ</span>
<span style="color:#FF6666">ABCD</span>
<span>Glenwood Springs</span>
```

**Output**

```
{'#FF2500': ['<span style="color:#FF2500">Glenwood Springs</span>', '<span style="color:#FF2500">XYZ</span>'], '#FF6666': ['<span style="color:#FF6666">ABCD</span>']}
```

It will return the dictionary with colors as key and the list of HTML lines corresponding to that colors as values.